# Ruby on Rails: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError with strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

In my RoR application, I have an `update_multiple` method that updates multiple records with the user's inputs. However, for some reason I get the error `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` despite using strong params. Can someone please help me fix this?

The `update_multiple` method in Recipients_Controller is as follows:

```
def update_multiple
    @email = Email.find_by_id(params[:email_id])
    if Recipient.update(params[:recipient].keys, params[:recipient].values)
        @listofcontacts = Recipient.where("id in (?)", params[:recipient].keys)
        @account = Account.find_by_id(@email.account_id)
        @listofcontacts.each do |f|
            recipient_message = @email.message
            recipient_message = recipient_message.gsub("VAR1", f.var1)
            contact = Contact.find_by_id(f.contact_id)
            @unsubscribe = Rails.application.message_verifier(:unsubscribe).generate(contact.id)
            UserEmails.send_email(@email, @account, contact.email, @unsubscribe, recipient_message).deliver_now
        end
        flash[:notice] = "recipients were updated"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'edit_multiple'
    end
end

private
def recipient_params
  params.require(:recipient).permit(:contact_id, :group_id, :email_id, :var1, :var2, :var3)
end
```

This method takes the user input from this form:

```
<%= form_for :recipient, :url => update_multiple_recipients_path, :html => { :method => :put }  do %>
    <fieldset>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <% if @email_message.upcase.include? "VAR1" %><th>VAR1</th><% end %>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :email_id, @email %>
                <% @recipients.each do |recipient| %>
                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                        <%= fields_for "recipient[]", recipient do |recipient_fields| %>
                        <td><%= recipient_fields.label recipient.contact.firstname %> <%= recipient_fields.label recipient.contact.surname %></td>
                        <% if @email_message.upcase.include? "VAR1" %><td><%= recipient_fields.text_field :var1, :required => true, :maxlength => 20 %></td><% end %>
                        <% end %>
                    </tr>
                <% end %>
            </tbody>
        </table></br>
        <%= submit_tag 'Send Email', {:class => 'btn btn-primary'} %></br>
        <%= link_to "Back", edit_email_path(@email) %>
    </fieldset> 
<% end %>
```

The `development.log` reads this:

```
Started PUT "/recipients/update_multiple" for ::1 at 2017-03-03 09:33:10 +0000
Processing by RecipientsController#update_multiple as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BJtQ56CW169tJ0Yqlc7BZNZk8SiTCauvkpNkXRUqVv4WESSS/DGFVDe3uQnfTxxDgif8lbg8THtmxHT9bOh0zw==", "email_id"=>"292", "recipient"=>{"635"=>{"var1"=>"ben"}}, "commit"=>"Send Email"}
  [1m[36mEmail Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "emails".* FROM "emails" WHERE "emails"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 292]]
  [1m[35mRecipient Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "recipients".* FROM "recipients" WHERE "recipients"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 635]]
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):
  app/controllers/recipients_controller.rb:15:in `update_multiple'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (1459.1ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (1449.1ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (3305.2ms)
```

Where it says `app/controllers/recipients_controller.rb:15:in 'update_multiple'`, it is pointing to the line `if Recipient.update(params[:recipient].keys, params[:recipient].values)`

I really cannot figure out why I am getting this error. Can someone please help me?

I have looked at various other SO questions and they seem to have been solved by `strong_params`, but mine already has `strong_params` declared and isn't working.

Comment: I could help you but I need a couple of extra info: first of all, I don't see anywhere a call to `recipient_params` which purpose is filter what comes from the form. As it isn't called it cannot be the guilty of that error... Second, could you a little chunk of the log where you see `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` ? Maybe we can found something helpful to understand from where it comes from

Comment: You're not using `recipient_params` anywhere, it's not enough to just declare it

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have updated the question with the log. @Iceman, how would I use `recipient_params` to then update multiple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems is this line:

```
if Recipient.update(params[:recipient].keys, params[:recipient].values)
```

You are passing `params` directly to the `update` method. You need to pass `recipient_params` into `update`:

```
if Recipient.update(recipient_params.keys, recipient_params.values)
```

**Update**

However, from your logs, it is apparent that params[:recipient] is returning a hash containing id/attribute pairs, not a single set of attributes. So you'll need to permit the attributes for each recipient `id` passed in `params`. I think this code should do it:

```
private
def recipient_params
  params.require(:recipient).permit(permit_for_each_recipient)
end

def permit_for_each_recipient
  params[:recipient].keys.inject({}){|h,k| h[k] = attributes_to_permit; h}
end

def attributes_to_permit
  [:contact_id, :group_id, :email_id, :var1, :var2, :var3]
end
```

Comment: This stops the error, but it does not update the data in the database for some reason

Answer (score 0):

**EDITING ANSWER AFTER COMMENTS**

First of all, some good [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) To help you to understand better how to use strong parameters.

Now, let's try to refactor a bit your code. Remember, methods larger than 4 lines are more risky to hide mistakes, avoid them if you can!

This is your code, I changed nothing except I moved some chunks of code into sub-methods

```
def update_multiple
  #this cannot  work because there is no instance to update
  if Recipient.update(params[:recipient].keys, params[:recipient].values)
    send_unsuscribe_emails
    flash[:notice] = "recipients were updated"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'edit_multiple'
  end
end

private

def recipient_params
  params.require(:recipient).permit(:contact_id, :group_id, :email_id, :var1, :var2, :var3)
end

def send_unsuscribe_emails
  @email = Email.find_by_id(params[:email_id])
  #this cannot work because params[:recipient].keys does not return a list of ids (probably you want womethink like recipients_params[:contact_id])
  @listofcontacts = Recipient.where("id in (?)", params[:recipient].keys)
  @account = Account.find_by_id(@email.account_id)
  @listofcontacts.each do |f|
    send_unsuscribe_email(f)
  end
end

def send_unsuscribe_email(f)
  recipient_message = @email.message.gsub("VAR1", f.var1)
  contact = Contact.find_by_id(f.contact_id)
  @unsubscribe = Rails.application.message_verifier(:unsubscribe).generate(contact.id)
  UserEmails.send_email(@email, @account, contact.email, @unsubscribe, recipient_message).deliver_now
end
```

and now the solution **could** be like this

```
def update_multiple
  @listofcontacts = Recipient.where("id in (?)", recipients_params[:contact_id])
  if @listofcontacts.update(recipient_params)
    send_unsuscribe_emails
    flash[:notice] = "recipients were updated"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'edit_multiple'
  end
end

private

def recipient_params
  params.require(:recipient).permit(:contact_id, :group_id, :email_id, :var1, :var2, :var3)
end

def send_unsuscribe_emails
  @email = Email.find_by_id(params[:email_id])
  @account = Account.find_by_id(@email.account_id)
  @listofcontacts.each do |f|
    send_unsuscribe_email(f)
  end
end

def send_unsuscribe_email(f)
  recipient_message = @email.message.gsub("VAR1", f.var1)
  contact = Contact.find_by_id(f.contact_id)
  @unsubscribe = Rails.application.message_verifier(:unsubscribe).generate(contact.id)
  UserEmails.send_email(@email, @account, contact.email, @unsubscribe, recipient_message).deliver_now
end
```

Of course I cannot test it so, probably it will crash somewhere, but more or less this is the idea.

Comment: This now gives me the error `undefined method 'keys' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Nice! that is due to how params are "transformed" by strong parameters. As you declared them like this `params.require(:recipient).permit(:contact_id, :group_id, :email_id, :var1, :var2, :var3)`
You will receive something like that `recipient: {contact_id: 1, group_id: 1, email_id: anemail@example.com, etc....}`
which means you could do two things depending on your needs:
`Recipient.update(contact_id: recipient_params[:contact_id])` to update only one attribute or  `Recipient.update(recipient_params)` to update everything

Comment: Apologies but I'm not following, would you mind giving more detail regarding the two things I could do as bearing in mind that this method is to update multiple records at once, I don't understand how these two things work.

Comment: Don't worry! Here we are to help. try this. 
`if Recipient.update(recipient_params)` what happens?

Comment: Thanks, this is just so frustrating. This gives me the error `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)`

Comment: Good! that is because you are calling `Recipient` which is a class, but `update` is an instance method. So you need to retrieve an instance of the recipient you want to update, otherwise rails cannot guess which one should be updated! Do you have anywhere something like `@recipient`?

Comment: No, I do not have anything like `@recipient`. The only thing I do have that's similar is `@listofcontacts = Recipient.where("id in (?)", params[:recipient].keys)` which finds all the contacts to be updated, and then I have `@listofcontacts.each do |f|` which gets the message for each recipient.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this still gives me the error `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137134/discussion-between-jonnyjava-net-and-ben-smith).